IC for CAN over EtherCAT (CoE)
I'm working on a motherboard for a motor driver that uses CAN for communication. I would like to implement EtherCAT, since the rest of the machine uses that.
I would prefer (for simplicity) to use an IC that would handle CAN over EtherCAT (CoE) to the "normal" CAN conversion.
I have found chips like the LAN9252 or ET1100, but I was not able to figure out how to use these with CoE. Does anyone know how I can implement this using either of these ICs (on something else)?
Using RS232 might also be an option.
Thank you in advance for any help!

Sorry but there is no question being asked. Please ask a question, add a question by editing.

...and asking for a product recommendation is off-topic and will get your question closed.

If you’re after a chip that has CAN and Ethercat out, then I’ve not seen one. I’d expect you’ll need a higher end microcontroller with CAN peripherals and an Ethernet MAC/PHY that does Ethercat like the two you have mentioned. The rest is software.  I have no idea where RS232 would figure in this.

Modern communications is generally though of in layers starting w/physical requirement up to protocol requirement. RS232 is a description of the lower layers and only for RS232. It looks like EtherCAT IEC 61158 describes most if not all layers for EtherCAT. Comparing the two is like comparing a walking trail with a highway. There are few if any rules to use the walking trail. To use the highway, there are a bunch or rules starting w/stuff like your car's street legal dimensions.

CoE is CANopen over EtherCATm not CAN over EtherCAT - it means that it uses concept of CANopen Layer 7 such as PDOs and ODs with EtherCAT as lower layer - but the protocol itself has some differences from CANopen over CAN (most notably PDU length and the state machine). If you want a converter, ask HMS. It will save you many headaches.

First of all, CoE is not "CAN" over EtherCAT. It is CANopen over EtherCAT - a much higher level protocol that runs on top of CAN. So, if the motor driver uses basic CAN, not CANopen, then CoE doesn't come into play at all. There is no standardized way of moving CAN messages over EtherCAT, since typically it'd be something custom on both ends of the wire. So no need for standardization.
So you can package CAN frames onto EtherCAT any way you want.
This is not usually handled directly in a chip - although it could be. It would be easiest to handle at hardware level using an FPGA that runs EtherCAT IP and a CAN MAC. A fixed EtherCAT message could fit several CAN frames. The FPGA would manage the exchange between the EtherCAT messages and CAN frames.
Alternatively, a microcontroller with built-in Industrial Ethernet MAC, qualified for EtherCAT use, is likely to have a CAN MAC as well. Then it would be just a small bit of software to connect the two. The actual functionality just copies data between the CAN stack buffers and the EtherCAT distributed memory buffers. So the application-specific code you want is like one or two screens of C. The rest is just setting up the CAN and EtherCAT stacks.
But, anyway, you won't need to implement any of it yourself. Just buy an off-the-shelf CAN-to-EtherCAT bridge, or CANopen-to-EtherCAT bridge. Many companies make those, and they should be easy to use. For "bare" CAN there's a simple configuration to deal with - usually packet filter parameters. For CANopen the configuration needed depends whether the bridge acts as a CANopen master or device (slave). EtherCAT-to-CANopen master bridges are more common, and that's what you need. The bridge should map the CAN-based CANopen device to make it visible from the EtherCAT master via CoE. Once set up, the bridged CANopen device will be available from the master (e.g. a PLC) just like any other CANopen device that uses CoE (say Beckhoff's drives).
